# pickadate set disabled days using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

I want to set the disabled days dynamically, depending on what was selected from a select-input.
My option has the following data field:

```
data-disableddays="2,3,4,5"
```

I have an onchange event on my select.
there I am getting the value of the data-disableddays:

```
var disableddays = $(this).find(':selected').data('disableddays');
```

The console.log output is correct (2,3,4,5)

When I am initializing the pickadate:

```
var picker = $('#tripstart').pickadate({
                        format: 'd.mm.yyyy',
                        min: new Date($mystart),
                        max: new Date($myend),
                        firstDay: 1,
                        disable: [
                          disableddays
                        ]
                      });
```

Nothing is happening. Replacing the variable disableddays with "2,3,4,5" everything is working well.
What do I have to do to make this variable working at this place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this

```
var disableddays = $(this).find(':selected').data('disableddays');
disableddays = disableddays.split(',').map(day=>parseInt(day));
var picker = $('#tripstart').pickadate({
                        format: 'd.mm.yyyy',
                        min: new Date($mystart),
                        max: new Date($myend),
                        firstDay: 1,
                        disable: disableddays
                      });
```

Basically, disabledays should be an array of integers.

Comment: Thank you. This is working! But I also want to extend it with a second option like a specific date: disable: disableddays, [new Date('2020-07-13')] when I dont use disable:[ ] then I can only pass either specific dates OR the disableddays... Any chance to fix this?

Comment: You can always push `new Date('2020-07-13')` to disableddays.
`disabledday.push(new Date('2020-07-13'))`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have used string "2,3,4,5" instead of array, you need to convert string to array, using `disableddays.split(",")`, like below:

```
var picker = $('#tripstart').pickadate({
                 format: 'd.mm.yyyy',
                 min: new Date($mystart),
                 max: new Date($myend),
                 firstDay: 1,
                 disable: disableddays.split(",")
             });
```